# Get result from db in a loop with completable future

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa, and I have logic which consists of 3 request in db which I want to run in parallel. I want to use for this purpose CompletableFuture.

In the end I need to build response object from result of 5 db query runs. 3 of them currently I'm running in a loop.

So I've create CompletableFuture

```
CompletableFuture<Long> totalFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  myRepository.getTotal());

CompletableFuture<Long> countFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  myRepository.getCount());
```

Then I'm plannig to use .allOf with this future. But I have problem with loop calls. How to rewrite it to use callable as in every request I need to pass value from request, and then sort into map, by key ?

```
Map<String, Integer> groupcount = new HashMap<>();
    request.ids().forEach((key, value) -> count.put(key, myRepository
            .getGroupCountId(value));
```

Comment: Could you explain "How to rewrite it to use callable as in every request I need to pass value from request, and then sort into map, by key ?" a little more throughly?

Comment: @Andrew Cheong I can post a solution which I don't like because I wanted to chain futures. I will post in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain a little more throughly I'm posting a code snippet which I want to chain but for now it works like this.

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> groupcount = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (var id : request.Ids().entrySet()) {
            completableFutures.add(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(someOperation, EXECUTOR_SERVICE)
                    .thenApply(v -> runQuery(v.getValues))
                    .thenAcceptAsync(res-> groupcount .put(v.key, res));
        }
CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).get();
```